# Nav-links to the bottom of sidebar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I have been trying to mess around with getting these three nav-links at the bottom of this sidebar I've created. I cannot manage to get them there. I am not really sure what else to try.

I have the background green on the nav links I am trying to begin at the bottom of the sidebar.

Sorry if this is a bad description, I am new to coding in general.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 bg-dark position-fixed" id="sticky-sidebar">
            <div
              class="nav flex-column flex-nowrap vh-100 overflow-auto text-white p2"
              id="pink-sidebar"
            >
              <a href="./index.html" class="nav-link"
                ><svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  height="2rem"
                  fill="#A0C3D2"
                  class="bi bi-house"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M8.707 1.5a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L.646 8.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L2 8.207V13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 15h9a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V8.207l.646.647a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293zM13 7.207V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V7.207l5-5z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>

              <a href="#" class="nav-link bottom">Gallery</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav-link bottom">About</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav-link bottom">Contact</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
#sticky-sidebar {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#pink-sidebar {
  background-color: #eac7c7;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: #a0c3d2;
  --bs-nav-link-hover-color: #EAE0DA;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: green;
}

/* #main {

} */
```

[My code being ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmZw.png)

I have tried making the sticky-sidebar display:flex, then having the .bottom nav-links align-self: flex-end; as well as trying flex-direction: column-reverse;

I expected the divs that the links with green background to begin at the bottom of the sidebar div, since it was declared as a flex-column. I'm not sure if I'm confusing bootstrap annotation with regular CSS annotation but this seems like an easy fix and it's frustrating not knowing how to fix it.

Comment: When I make the #sticky-sidebar display: flex, then align-self: flex-end the .bottom classes, it changes where they move on the x axis. I'm not sure why this is. Even if I go further and make the flex-direction: column, it will still only change the .bottom navs left and right. I need them to move vertically to the bottom. of the side-navbar.

Comment: Is this the full relevant code? when I run the code in your example it's just a navbar in a row and not a column like seen in your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `margin-bottom: auto` on the home link, which is `mb-auto` in Bootstrap like this:

```html
<a href="./index.html" class="nav-link mb-auto">
```

Hence the full code will be:

```css
#sticky-sidebar {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#pink-sidebar {
  background-color: #eac7c7;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  /* display: flex; Removed because Bootstrap .nav already adds display:flex */
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: #a0c3d2;
  --bs-nav-link-hover-color: #EAE0DA;
}

.bottom {
  /*background-color: green!important;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 bg-dark position-fixed" id="sticky-sidebar">
      <div class="nav flex-column flex-nowrap vh-100 overflow-auto text-white p2" id="pink-sidebar">
        <a href="./index.html" class="nav-link mb-auto"><svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  height="2rem"
                  fill="#A0C3D2"
                  class="bi bi-house"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M8.707 1.5a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L.646 8.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L2 8.207V13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 15h9a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V8.207l.646.647a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293zM13 7.207V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V7.207l5-5z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>

        <a href="#" class="nav-link bottom">Gallery</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link bottom">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link bottom">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```